# How can I generate JPA metamodel in spring-boot with gradle?(+ lombok)

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, gradle, spring-data-jpa, metamodel

I want add JPA metamodel to my project - `Spring boot + gradle`

I find a lot of examles how can i do it but all with `Maven`. Also I find this site: https://plugins.gradle.org/search?term=metamodel

and try first three plugins. With each plugins I get errors:  `error: cannot find symbol` in classes marked lombok `@Builder` annotation and some classes is not `entity`. It is example some plugin:

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.iboyko.gradle.plugins:jpamodelgen-plugin:1.0.1"
    }
 }

    dependencies {
        compile ('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen')
    }
```

1) Which plugin or method is the most official (correct) to create `JPA metamodel` in Spring `boot + spring-data-jpa + gradle` ?

2) How can I specify only the package with  `entities`  and not scan another classes?

3) how to make friends with it with `lombok`?

**EDIT**

I add this code to gradle file:

```
sourceSets.configureEach { sourceSet ->
    tasks.named(sourceSet.compileJavaTaskName).configure {
        options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = file("$buildDir/generated/sources/java")
    }
}
```

and it generate `classes_` fine. After that I mark

```
generated/sources/java
```

folder ass root of generated classes(rigth clik to this folder and mark as)

[image]

After that I try import generated classes in my repository and IDE show this:

[image]

For each module I have 2 module - `my_module` and `my_module_main`(I don't understand why) and all classes generate in `my_module` but all code in `my_module_main`. If I add this dependency - I have this:

[image]

and in generated class I have this:
[image]

Answer (score 9):

I was struggling through the same issue. Finally I got it working by adding both dependencies in both compileOnly and annotationProcessor forms. Don't ask me why, but it somehow works.

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.10'
compileOnly 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen'
annotationProcessor('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen')
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you use Spring Initalizr to generate the project?

This is what you get from Initializr (expect the jpamodelgen that I added by myself):

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    runtime('com.h2database:h2')
    compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
    compileOnly ('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen')
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

// Add source set to define where the generated source code should go to
sourceSets.configureEach { sourceSet ->
    tasks.named(sourceSet.compileJavaTaskName).configure {
        options.annotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory = file("$buildDir/generated/sources/java")
    }
}
```

You can find a demo project on GitHub:

https://github.com/simasch/demo-gradle-jpa

**In IntelliJ you can right click on generated/sources/java and choose**

Comment: And how can I generate JPA-metamodel with your example?

Comment: the dependency compileOnly ('org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen') will generate the _ classes automatically

Comment: This is very strange, since I have such a dependency and it does not work. Therefore, I began to look for a suitable plugin for this.

Comment: how do you think it does not work? You will find the _ classes in /build/classes there will be no source code

Comment: In this folder, I have all the original classes of my application and there is not one (and not in one folder) class MyClass_.  I think you are mistaken. To generate a metamodel you need not only a dependency, but a plugin to start generating this model. At least in maven it works that way.

Comment: Please checkout my demo project: https://github.com/simasch/demo-gradle-jpa and even in Maven you don't need the plugin

Comment: Yes, in your example, everything works. But I do not. I am puzzled. It seems to be the same

Comment: I was able to break your example. added these dependencies `annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'`

Comment: Generated classes not recognized in IDE

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: Intellij IDE. I try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/47903348/4781349 But IDE say - `Error:(9, 17) java: duplicate class: domain.entity.AllowedValue_`.

Comment: Have you enabled annotation processing: https://immutables.github.io/apt.html#intellij-idea

Comment: Have you tried to clone my app? Do you have the same issues?

Comment: Yes, I start your app. It work fine and help me. But I can not use generated classes in your app too. Because IDE not see it.

Comment: I added a solution to have the generated source code in a separated directory and how you can add this directory to make IntelliJ use the code

Comment: Also check out this solution with the apt plugin https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42441844/annotation-processor-in-intellij-and-gradle

Comment: I eddit my question

Comment: @SimonMartinelli: your demo works with Gradle 4.10.2 (the included wrapper), but unfortunately generates no classes with Gradle 5.5.1 - just tested.